# L'Hospital's rule:Example Needed

Tags: limits

I just thought of a certain question regarding L'Hospital's rule.

The rule can be applied in indeterminate functions of form $f(x)/g(x)$

> Are there any example where f'(x)/g'(x) is again indeterminate and
>   f''(x)/g''(x) and so on indefinitely (like its looping)?What should be
>   the approach in those particular cases?

I'm just going through Calc 2 course..so please suit your answer to my level of understanding.

Comment: The classical example is $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$; after rearranging $f'(x)/g'(x)$ you get $\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}}{x}$ and the next application of l'Hôpital brings you at the starting point.

Comment: see here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LHospitalsRule.aspx

Comment: Do Lhospital again, in some cases  Lhospital doesnt help

Comment: A joke, but in principle correct: Find $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^x}{e^x}$ using the Rule.

Answer (score 2):

Yes  a good example is $f(x)=e^{ax}$ and $g(x)=e^{bx}$. $a,b \neq 0$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{ax}}{e^{bx}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{a^n e^{ax}}{b^n e^{bx}}$$

In short the ratio between two exponential functions as $x$ goes to $\infty$ cannot be solved by L'Hopitals Rule.

Comment: Assumed that $a,b$ are not zero and have the same sign.

Comment: @ajotatxe Yes, I was assuming that.

Comment: so how should it be solved?

Comment: $\frac{e^{ax}}{e^{bx}}=e^{(a-b)x}$.

Comment: It is $\infty$, $\lim e^{x(a-b)}=\infty$

Comment: In this example: 1) $b < 0$ or 2) $a > b$

Answer (score 1):

Make for example $f(x)=2^x$ and $g(x)=3^x$ and the limit at $x\to\infty$.

Of course, the limit can be easily calculated by other means.

Comment: Such as $\lim (\frac{2}{3})^x$